# Firefox12: multiple css classes don't seem to work for me

Tags: firefox, css

I have a few buttons on my webpage in different colors. I have one class for the shape of the button, and then a few classes that give them colors.

```
.button    {
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue W01 75 Bold", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;    
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}   

a.button {
  color: #333;
}

.black.button    {
  background-color: #dedede;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.1, #D3D3D3), color-stop(0.45, #EFEFEF), color-stop(0.90, #D3D3D3));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient((linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.1, #D3D3D3), color-stop(0.45, #EFEFEF), color-stop(0.90, #D3D3D3));
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=##EFEFEF, endColorStr=##D3D3D3);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#EFEFEF, endColorstr=#D3D3D3)";
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
}


.black.button:hover    {
  background: #E2E2E2;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#E2E2E2, endColorStr=#E2E2E2);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#E2E2E2, endColorstr=#E2E2E2)";
}

.orange.button    {
  background-color:  #ffaa44;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.22, rgb(255,144,9)), color-stop(0.81, rgb(255,170,68)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(255,144,9) 22%, rgb(255,170,68) 81%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#ffaa44, endColorStr=#ff9009);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffaa44, endColorstr=#ff9009)";
}   

.orange.button:hover    {
  background: #ff9009;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#ff9009, endColorStr=#ff9009);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff9009, endColorstr=#ff9009)";
}
```

I use them like:

```
<a class="orange button" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

This works in Chrome and Safari but does not work in Firefox12 (and IE). All I see is a white box with 'ClickMe' (So probably the .button is applied, but not .orange)

From what I read, this is supported in Firefox. But I cannot figure what is wrong in my stylesheet.

When I do an 'Inspect Element', Firefox shows the class as a.orange.button, but in the Styles tab, it doesnot display these classes. It is picking my stylesheet as the rest of the page is displayed okay.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVdCR/) from your code.

Comment: Could you say specifically what does not work (like does which classes do work)? worked for me after `background: -webkit-gradient(...` and `border-radius:...' where removed. I'm using FF13 and it works just so you know (minus webkit stuff and empty border radius).

Comment: where is the actuall css code? the ellipses dots indicate something is missing.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: Thanks for pointing to this tool. If this works in my firefox, does that mean that actual css should work too? Implying that the error I see is somewhere else and not in this piece of code?

Comment: @Kyomu: I do not see any of the styles, no button, no color. Just a plain text with link.

Comment: Possibly, and if it works in jsFiddle it should work normally.

Comment: @zaphod If it works in the jsFiddle, it should work in your code either :). In other words: the problem is in your code.

Comment: @Michael Paulukonis: The classes were quite big with gradients, shadow, etc. hence I put in ellipsis to make it simple. I also tried removing all those properties, keeping just background-color and border radius, and yet multiple classes do not work. So I think it is more to do with multiple classes than CSS properties within those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you remove invalid CSS code. I'm wondering if you have these exact lines in your original CSS code (with `...` and unclosed brackets - which should cause the problem):

- `background: -webkit-gradient(...`
- `border-radius:...`

[Cleaned up jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RVdCR/1/)

The problem is surely not with multiple classes. [They work fine in every modern browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t14).

---

**UPDATE:** I found the issue based on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFLHW/). It is this declaration:

```
.black.button    {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient((linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.1, #D3D3D3), color-stop(0.45, #EFEFEF), color-stop(0.90, #D3D3D3));
}
```

You have one more opening `(` than needed right after `-moz-linear-gradient`.

Correct version ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFLHW/3/)):

```
.black.button    {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.1, #D3D3D3), color-stop(0.45, #EFEFEF), color-stop(0.90, #D3D3D3));
}
```

Comment: No, I do not have ellipsis in my stylesheet; it was just that those classes were quite big and I did not want clutter in the question. Am looking at the jsFiddle with the entire classes, and it works. So need to pore through the stylesheet to see why it doesn't work when loaded directly.

Comment: @zaphod If you manage to share something that shows it not working, I'm happy to help.

Comment: I updated the question with my actual classes. What happens is that I see a white box with radius (probably .button) and 'Click Me'. The .orange is not applied. This is on Firefox12 (and IE). I am missing something, but cannot figure out what. Would appreciate if you could please take a look.

Comment: @zaphod Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFLHW/) if anyone else wants to check. I confirm the description in Firefox 13.

Comment: @zaphod Found your problem I guess. That unclosed bracket was eating up the rest of your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the following

```
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top left, white, black );
```

`-webkit-gradient` is for webkit browsers -- like Chrome and Safari; Firefox is not a webkit browser.

see http://jsfiddle.net/Wfxym/

Some notes found @ [linear gradients](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/linear-gradients/) and especially [Cross-browser CSS gradient](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient) (details on the Firefox implementation can be found on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient)

Comment: That's true, but a `-webkit-gradient` definition should not cause all styles to not work.